# Reusing routes for inbound/outbound communication

Tags: java, apache-camel, netty

I have the following two routes:

Route 1

```
from("netty:tcp://localhost:5050?textline=true&encoder=#customStringEncoder&decoder=#customDecoder")
            .routeId("inboundSocketRoute")
            .doTry()
            .unmarshal(beanIO)
            .bean(inboundInterfaceProcessor, "processInterfaceData")
            .doCatch(ValidationException.class, UnidentifiedRecordException.class, InvalidRecordException.class)
            .bean(inboundInterfaceProcessor, "processInterfaceDataError")
            .end();
```

Route 2

```
String server = "123.45.67.89:5050";
from("jms://queue:evOutboundDataInterface")
            .routeId("outboundInterfaceRoute")
            .doTry()
            .bean(outboundInterfaceProcessor, "processOutboundData")
            .to("netty:tcp://" + server + "?textline=true&requestTimeout=10000&encoder=#customStringEncoder&decoder=#customDecoder")
            .bean(outboundInterfaceProcessor, "processSequence")
            .doCatch(ReadTimeoutException.class)
            .bean(outboundInterfaceProcessor, "handleTimeout")
            .doCatch(ConnectException.class)
            .bean(outboundInterfaceProcessor, "handleConnectionError")
            .end();
```

Route 1 is triggered by incoming data from an external server. The incoming data is parsed by BeanIO and eventually ends up in my `InterfaceProcessor`, which treats inbound data. Route 2 is triggered by a JMS message (which is sent by my software) and it should send a message back to the external server on the same port.

In my current setup, I start my own server (route 1) and client (route 2). I don't think this will work, as both connections are always active. This way, when I want to send a message to the external server from route 2, it probably won't be able to connect to the external server. However, when I receive a message on route 1, I am able to send a message back to the external server (from within the processor that is bound to that route) by having `inboundInterfaceProcessor.processInterfaceData()` return the `String` that will be sent to the external server.

Because I'm able to send a message back to the external server from route 1, I'm thinking about triggering `inboundInterfaceProcessor` from `outboundInterfaceProcessor` to send a message to the external server from route 2. How should I do this? Is this even possible with Camel/Netty? Or should I use another approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by having the external server poll for data that would normally be sent through the second route. Every message is answered with an acknowledge message, so when this acknowledgement is received by the inbound interface, I can check for more outgoing interface data. It isn't ideal, but it works. :)